# Run-time/Compile-time initialization of char***

Tags: c++

How do I initialize `char*** p` at run-time or compile-time?

Comment: Using raw pointers in c++ is usually bad. Using double pointers in c++ is crazy. Triple pointer in c++... well I never saw it

Comment: Obligatory link to [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: You don't. Use _something less painful_ instead.

Comment: I once wrote a python script that did this: http://pastebin.com/kQuRbCFk

Answer (score 6):

**Initialize with a null pointer**

```
char*** p = 0; //or NULL, or nullptr
```

**Another option**

```
char x;
char *y = &x;
char **z = &y;
char ***p = &z;
```

**Allocating memory?**

```
char *** p = new char**[dim1];
for(int i = 0; i < dim1; ++i)
{
   p[i] = new char*[dim2];
   for(int j = 0; j < dim2; ++j)
   {
       p[i][j] = new char[dim3];
   }
}
```

Comment: How do I do a run-time initialization?

Comment: @programmer: I have no idea what you're talking about. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: if i have function that takes (int **ptr) is it possible to iterate through all the elements of a 2 dimension array?

Comment: @programmer: You can't deduce the dimensions of your 2D array from an int**. You should also pass the dimensions. And yes, you can iterate a pointer as if it were an array

Answer (score 3):

Well, here's one example:

```
char A = 'A';
char *pA = &A;
char **ppA = &pA;
char ***p = &ppA;   // Now `***p` will dereference all the way back to 'A'
```

Comment: thanks..this is an example of compile-time initialization. How do I do a run-time initialization?

Comment: @programmer: Actually, this is run-time. The addresses of `A`, `pA`, etc. are not known until run-time (and even if they were, the `&` operator runs at run-time). What do you mean by compile-time initialization? The only thing I can think of is initializing to a compile-time constant (probably 0)